# Libgdx scene2d window title size

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

After setting up a scene2d window and setting a title, id like to be able to adjust the height of the title bar.

If thats not possible is there a way of finding the current height of the bar? as this would make placing tables and other actors within it a lot easier?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height of the back of the title bar by modifying the 9 patch graphic used for the background of the window.  It's just the top of the window image.

The title available via window.getTitleLabel() is the text label placed on top of the top of the underlying window graphic.

Answer (score -1):

You actor will always be added bellow the title bar, you can adjust using padTop(). 
To change the title bar size you can change the font of the title size.

I never found a better way to manage this.

Comment: *To change the title bar size you can change the font of the title size.* Doesn't work, it stays the same height but the text overflows.

Comment: My answer is 4 years old, I havent touched the framework for a while .

Answer (score -1):

you can get the title label through window.getTitleLabel(), then modify it.